# Multiple column sum and update total field [MySQL]

Tags: mysql

I have table named 'spending_list'.

```
 id , food,  tea,  snack, others, coffee, total 

 1  , 8000 , 0,    0,     1500,   4400,   0

 2  , 0 ,    4000, 500,   0,      1500,   0
```

I want to insert total field  using sum ( food + tea + snack + others + coffee).

I don't know how can make SQL operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a matter of simple

```
UPDATE spending_list
SET total=food+tea+snack+others+coffee
;
```

Which you could encapsulate in a trigger if needed.

Having said that, I don't believe it is a good idea most of the time: Unless you need a sort index on total and the table is large, this denormalization will do not much good but may potentially create problems at least in the readability department.

Comment: How can do encapsulation?  I'm newbie on MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the sum...

```
Update spending_list set total = (food + tea + snack + others + coffee)
```